# Does projection make Meteor observeChanges more performant?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to observe changes on one or maybe two, but definitely not all the properties of a document.

I was wondering if the `observeChanges` function would be any more performant if called on a cursor that has been projected?

***Without** projection*

```
MyCollection.find().observeChanges(
  changed: (_id, fields) ->
    if fields.myProperty?
      doMyFunctionality(fields.myProperty)
)
```

***With** projection*

```
MyCollection.find({}, myProperty: 1).observeChanges(
  changed: (_id, fields) ->
    doMyFunctionality(fields.myProperty)
)
```

(Assuming that the documents in `MyCollection` have at least another property that is changed at some point.)

Comment: In the future I recommend you not to post coffeescript code. The converted output is more readable to not coffeescript programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, whether or not you directly use `observeChanges`, your app will be more performant if you limit the fields requested by `find` in your publish functions because it:

1. fetches less data from the underlying database (bandwidth)
2. pushes less data to connected clients (bandwidth)
3. maintains a smaller shared result set (memory)

If you are using [oplog tailing](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver), I'm uncertain if there is any significant computational savings to limiting the fields. My intuition is that it must help because the driver can potentially skip any changes to non-observed fields - I just don't know how significant that effect is.

It's absolutely true that you will reduce CPU using a fields projection when using the old poll-and-diff algorithm because it literally diffs the documents. The fewer fields there are to compare, the more efficiently it executes.

For additional details, I'd recommend watching [Making Mongo Realtime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dzX_LEbZyI) by David Glasser.